# Exim4: How to block a list of recipient addresses

Tags: exim

To catch mail send to any recipient I have added the following router directive in my exim4 configuration:

```
local_catchall:
 debug_print = "R: catchall for $local_part@$domain"
 driver = redirect
 domains = +local_domains
 allow_fail
 allow_defer
 data = johanna
```

How can I exclude some **recipient** addresses like it is possible with sender addresses per:

```
acl_check_data: 
 strong textdeny senders = /etc/deny_senders
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`condition`](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-generic_options_for_routers.html) router option and a [single-key query](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html) like

```
condition = ${lookup {$local_part@$domain} lsearch {/etc/deny_recips} {0} {1}}
```

You could use the [`acl_smtp_rcpt`](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-access_control_lists.html) instead, but note that it's for SMTP input only, extend if necessary:

```
deny recipients = /etc/deny_recips
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
deny
  condition = ${lookup{$local_part}nwildlsearch{/path/to/black.list}{yes}{no}}                                                                          
  message = User is black listed. Go away.
```

The advantage is that you can use regexp in the `black.list` file. The disadvantage is that you can user regexp in the `black.list` file. Therefore you need a lot of testing (via `ecim -v -bt 1.2.3.4 …`) to *make sure* your regexp is correct.

My file `black.list` looks like thus:

```
^Diana.*$
^Evelina.*$
^Julia.*$ 
^Katherin.*$
^Olga.*$
^Violette.*$
^fax$                                                                                                                                                   
^sales$
```

See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/395764/10526) if you are unfortunate enough to use Debian/Ubuntu…