# exim4 & CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE

Tags: ubuntu, exim

I am running a ubuntu server (I got convinced and there is not one day that I do not regret it!) which runs Exim. Deep within the split configuration's ACL files, I found this:

```
  # This hook allows you to hook in your own ACLs without having to             
  # modify this file. If you do it like we suggest, you'll end up with          
  # a small performance penalty since there is an additional file being         
  # accessed. This doesn't happen if you leave the macro unset.                 
  .ifdef CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE                                              
  .include CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE                                            
  .endif
```

A search `CHECK_RCPT_LOCAL_ACL_FILE` yields many such stanza but no where does it tell you *where to create the variable* or *what the file should look like*. The latter should be obvious as it will just contain some more ACL commands. However, the former is a mystery… Anyone got an idea?

I did try to ask this on ask.ubuntu and as usual got nothing whatsoever…

Note that the following stanza works just fine in the `conf.d/acl/30_exim4-config_check_rcpt` file but modifying system files like that will lead to trouble the next time Ubuntu decides to update…

```
  deny
   condition = ${lookup{$local_part}nwildlsearch{/etc/exim4/black.list}{yes}{no}}
   logwrite = :main,reject: $sender_host_address - $local_part@$domain is only used by spammers
   message = User is black listed. Go away.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this ACL to the file `/etc/exim4/include/check_rcpt_local_acl`

It's work for me.